# iOS api for shazam type service?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, api, shazam

I have an app and would like to know if there is any kind of API for a service similar to Shazam where I can hold my phone up to a music source and be told of the song guess? It could work well with my app, but I can't find anything about Shazam API and I don't know any other service that does what I want (but am open to anything)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web-API for shazam or a similar service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994221/web-api-for-shazam-or-a-similar-service)

Comment: ShazamKit is built into the iOS SDK in this year 2021 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audio recognition services are provided by a number of companies, many of which license these services for a fee.  None are cheap, requiring significant repositories of signatures / music catalogs and computational capacity.  Check out the folks who own the technology used by Shazam - [Landmark Digital Services](http://www.landmarkdigital.com), the makers of Soundhound - [Midomi](http://midomi.com), or [Gracenote's MusicID](http://www.gracenote.com/products/musicid/).  There are others, but these are probably three of the biggest players currently.

**UPDATE (11/8/12):**  To note, [Shazam](http://shazam.com) apparently has reacquired the rights to the recognition technology and Landmark Digital is now defunct.  Also, as noted in another answer, [Echonest](http://echoprint.me) now provides a recognition technology, [Echoprint](http://echoprint.me), that for some uses appears to be free.

Answer (score 3):

The free and open source alternative is [Echo Nest](http://the.echonest.com/) / [Echo Print](http://echoprint.me/).  They claim to have a database of 30 million songs and 1.5 million artists, and they provide free access for both commercial and non-commercial use.  Probably worth checking out!

Update: [here's the Echo Nest iOS library](https://github.com/echonest/enios)

Answer (score 2):

[ACRCloud](http://www.acrcloud.com) supports Music/Audio search engine and SDK for iOS/Android/Linux, which could be downloaded after registration (http://console.acrcloud.com/signup).
There are three tiers:

- Free tier, for demo/prototyping
- Accelerating tier, for startups
- Commercial tier

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: Yes, there are 50 million global songs' fingerprint in ACRCloud's Database,   the customer could use this database or create their own uploaded database for recognizing. For those customer who want to do demo or prototype, free tier could be used, 1000 audio queries could used per day.

Comment: and please also see the sample code we have provided:
https://github.com/acrcloud/

Comment: yes, acrcloud is better than gracenote: you can refer to : http://www.jianshu.com/p/69e5c67aade1